# Using print() in twilio

Tags: python, twilio

After I installed `twilio`, I use `print(twillio.version)`:

```
import twilio

print(twilio.version)
```

there's an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a silly question, but: have you verified that the `twilio` module is _supposed_ to have a version attribute? Does it say in the documentation that it does? (not a rhetorical question, I really want to know)

Comment: Thank you very much, I have updated my question.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Can you provide a link to the twilio documentation where it says that you should be trying to do `print(twilio.version)` in order to check whether it was installed correctly? I'm looking at [Twilio - test your installation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python#test-your-installation) and I don't see anything like that.

Comment: @Kevin I can confirm the command to print the version is wrong, it should be `print(twilio.__version__)` (see here https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/twilio/__init__.py )

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which version of Twilion you installed. But 6.19.1 has `__version__`, not version on module level.

```
>>> import twilio
>>> dir(twilio)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__',     '__version__', '__version_info__']
>>> twilio.__version__
'6.19.1'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helpful to me

Answer (score 2):

While not all Python modules support it (so I'm not sure about Twilio), you can try to execute `twilio.__version__` instead.

If that doesn't work, maybe first try executing `twilio -v` or `twilio --version` on the command line to see if the module has been installed properly, or to get the version number like that.

Hope this helps!